# Understanding a precondition for the law of large numbers

Tags: statistics, law-of-large-numbers

Discussions of the law of large numbers frequently begin like this:

> Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable, and let $X_1$, $X_2$, $\ldots$ be an infinite sequence of i.i.d. copies of $X$.  Let $\bar{X}_n := \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)$ be the empirical averages of this sequence.

But this is confusing to me; in particular, this is because I cannot imagine a scenario where (given the constraints above) it is *not* the case that

$$
X = \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)
$$

But it must be possible for the left-hand side of this equation to diverge from the right-hand side (otherwise the law of large numbers wouldn't be interesting).

So does there exist a simple example where

$$
X \ne \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + \ldots + X_n)?
$$

Comment: Suppose $X_i$ was a simple bernoulli process ($0$ or $1$ with probablity $\frac 12$), and take $n=2$. Then $X=\frac 12(X_1+X_2)$ Then $X$ is $0$ or $1$ with probability $\frac 14$, and $\frac 12$ with probability $\frac 12$.  Thus it is not equal to the underlying single process.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this example. How is it possible that $X$ could have value ${1 \over 2}$? $X$ has the same domain as $X_1$ and $X_2$: $\{0,1\}$ (and for neither of these inputs does $X$ have value $1/2$). Am I missing something?

Comment: If, say, $X_1=1$ and $X_2=0$ (a probability $\frac 14$ event) then $X=\frac 12(1+0)=\frac 12$.

Comment: To be clear:  this is the usual situation!  Not a pathology.  Normal distributions are invariant under this operation, other distributions (eg bernoulli or uniform) converge to normal ones (a consequence of the Central Limit Theorem).

Comment: Should say:  I think I used different notation than you did.  Let's let $Y=\frac 12(X_1+X_2)$ instead.

Comment: But if the functions $X_1 = 1 \ne 0 = X_0$, then $X_0$ and $X_1$ fail to be i.i.d. copies.

Comment: Also, just so I'm clear on this: here $+$ is designating normal function addition, correct? That is, $X = X_1 + X_2$ implies that $X(k) = X_1(k) + X_2(k)$?

Comment: Ok, I see the problem.  $X_1$ and $X_2$ are equal as random variables, they are not equal.  Thus $X_1$ is the toss of fair red coin, and $X_2$ is the toss of a fair blue coin.  They are absolutely not required to have the same value in each observation (that's the first i in iid).

Comment: To your question, yes.  "+" just means addition.  But your confusion lies in that "independence" assumption.  That's the key point of random variables.  Two independent samples of a fixed variable are likely not to match.

Comment: Ok. So it needn't be that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same values. In your example, $X_0$ could be the constant function $0$ (so that no matter whether the coin lands on heads or tails, we have $X_0(E) = 0$ and vice versa for $X_1(E) = 1$). But then in that case wouldn't it hold that $E[X_0] \ne E[X_1]$? That, too, is a precondition of the law of large numbers (unless I'm mistaken). If that's the case, your counter-example doesn't apply to this context, and I'm still left wondering how this theorem is interesting.

Comment: I don't get your example.  If the underlying process is constant, then of course all observations of it coincide.